# How to calculate cosine similarity between scalar and vector?

Tags: python, nlp, cosine-similarity

How to calculate cosine similarity between scalar and vector in Python?

I am trying to multiply the output of a ngram model's probability with the output of a pretrained word2vec model to rerank the next possible word using word prediction. (Natural language processing)

Is there a library for this? I tried sklearn's here:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html

But it only takes in two vectors to calculate pairwise cosine similarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **cosine similarity** is, by definition, a measure of similarity between two vectors (see [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)). If you imagine the two vectors in an Euclidean space, it measures how aligned their orientations are.
Therefore the cosine similarity between a vector and a scalar is not defined.

What exactly do you want to measure?

Comment: Good point! Thank you for clarifying that. I've added what I am trying to measure above.